# How to write location, reference and timestamp data types on Firestore with Python's SDK?

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

Documentation goes as far as explaining how to write the following data types:

```
data = {
  u'stringExample': u'Hello, World!',
  u'booleanExample': True,
  u'numberExample': 3.14159265,
  u'dateExample': datetime.datetime.now(),
  u'arrayExample': [5, True, u'hello'],
  u'nullExample': None,
  u'objectExample': {
    u'a': 5,
    u'b': True
  }
}
```

I am migrating a Mongo DB collection into FireStore.

This is my code so far:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

def initialize_firestore():
  cred = credentials.Certificate('admin.json')
  app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
  db = firestore.client()
  return db

db.collection('My_Collection').document('desired_iD').set('Document_to_write')
```

I would like to write a document with reference and location fields plus a custom date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the response(res) & initializing dictionary (Document_to_write):

```
Document_to_write['date_type'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(res['created'], "date format in string")
Document_to_write['reference_type'] = db.document(u'Collection_Name/'+res['collection_id'])
Document_to_write['location_type'] = firestore.GeoPoint(res['latitude'], res['longitude'])
```

Follow to save with selected method.